# String Concatenation Oddities

Tags: c, string, char, concatenation

I give up, i just dont know why this doesn't work:

```
int main(){
    int i;
    char destination[1000];
    char* str = "S:15 B:20 B A:15",letra;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
        letra = str[i];
        printf("%c",letra);
        strcat(destination,letra);
    }
    printf("%s",destination);
    return 0;
}
```

I just want to be able to concatenate a string to other, this only takes a string and copies it char by char to another empty string (which has enough size), but it doesn't work for whatever reason. If instead of using "letra" i use a literal string in strcat, it works, but if i use "letra" it fails, even when "letra" is a valid char and if i printf "letra" it works perfectly.

Can anyone lend me a hand? i am completely stuck, i am missing something simple but i don't know what it is.

Comment: `strcat` takes two strings, not a string and a character.

Comment: you can do away with the loop, just `strcat(destination, str)`

Comment: And the two strings need to be properly null-terminated. Your `destination` buffer has junk data.

Comment: `char* a, b` defines `a` as a `char*` ... and `b` as a `char`!  The `*` only applies to the variable name, not the type.

Comment: What commandline options are you using for your compiler? Turn the warnings up and read them.

Comment: @librik That might be intended as otherwise `letra = str[i];` wouldn't work.

Comment: Why not spend a few minutes' effort to search the internet for examples of `strcat` use?

Comment: It seems i should have explained myself better

What i want to do in my complete program is:

I have a string, which has a the travel time to hours to another city in a format "city:time city2:time2 city3:time3....". The problem, the name of the city can have spaces, so, i cant use strtok. What i want to do is, iterate lover the line and check the char. If is the first char or the char is different from space, i add it directly to my new string, if the char is an space, then i check the previous character, if it an int, then it means its a separator space, so instead i add a ";"

Comment: to my new string, but if the previous characters is not an int, then its part of the name of the city, so i add it directly to my new string. Basically, i just want to be able to add whatever char to a string, and i cant do it. copying the entire string is not an option. Any simple way to do this?

Comment: You might want to re-word your original question with what you're trying to achieve, with sample input and sample output strings.

Comment: Yeah, i should but i fixed my problem, one of the harshest comments (i actually investigated for quite a while) was the key, fixed it with this

char temp[ 2 ];
temp[ 0 ] = letra;
temp[ 1 ] = '\0';
strcat(destination,temp);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. `destination` is not initialized and so the call to `strcat` is invalid. You have to supplied a valid C string as the first parameter.
2. `strcat` operates on C strings, not on `char`. So you cannot pass `letra` as the second parameter.
3. You call `strlen(str)` every time around the loop.
4. Using `strcat` to add a character at a time is extremely inefficient.

The loop itself is rather pointless in this example, because it can be replaced by a single `strcpy` call. But I understand from the comments, that in the real code you want to add characters in a conditional manner. That's going to involve iterating over the source string at which point you are best populating the destination string in a similar manner.

You might write code like this:

```
size_t i = 0;
char destination[1000];
const char* str = "S:15 B:20 B A:15";
const char* p = str;
while (p)
{
    if (appendThisChar(*p))
        destination[i++] = *p;
    p++;
}
destination[i] = '\0';
```

I've neglected any checks for buffer overrun in the interests of simplicity, but obviously in real code you would make sure you could not write over the end of the buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it:

```
char temp[ 2 ];
temp[ 0 ] = letra;
temp[ 1 ] = '\0';
strcat(destination,temp);
```

Comment: `destination` still is not initialized.  Need `destination[0] = '\0';` or something.

Comment: You'll want to do a `destination[0] = '\0'` before the loop as well to make sure strcat does what you expect.

Comment: `strcat` is a really inefficient way to populate a string character by character. Please don't believe that you have solved your problem.

Comment: Once you are satisfied with your answer, mark it answered, or pick _another_ answer that suits.  Either way, its a good idea to pick one (click green check mark visible to the right of desired answer)